# Should we have a Meta thread for reqesting reopen and undeletion votes like Mathematics.SE.Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, vote-to-reopen, vote-to-undelete

[Mathematics SE Meta - Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today)

From the link above:

> The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the
>   community on posts that may require reopen and undeletion votes. A
>   request should be posted as an answer below (one request per answer).

Seems like a useful thread to have on Stack Overflow and other SE sites. Why don't we have this?

Comment: We have [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @Xufox You're not allowed to post your own posts there.

Comment: I don't think that would work at the scale of SO. Math has around 400 questions a day, SO 7000

Comment: Just to be clear, so that you don't think "Votes on meta are different" and ignore the downvote, I am downvoting this question because it is not useful as currently written because of 
lack of information. You don't explain at all what you are linking to, and you just say that it seems useful without any justification as to why.

Comment: I came in here looking for a javascript pun.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier puns are for children, not groan ups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple reason: scale.

No other site on the network comes close to having the same scale of traffic on it. Having thousands of people ask for a review of why their question was closed is already a job for the review queues, which are capable of handling this site's scale.

Comment: There is no review queue for undeletions though, and no the list under /tools?tab=delete is not a substitute.

Comment: @user000001:  Ethically speaking, there *can't* be a delete review queue.  Questions get deleted for very good reasons - there's a lot of stuff in those deleted questions that average users shouldn't ever have to see, moderate or witness.  Users who get their question deleted and have a problem with it are a relative minority compared to questions which are deleted for valid and true reasons.